# How to fix "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" in java programming

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u03pJ.png) i want to view the data that i already add but it shows exception. can refer to the image

```
public static void viewRecord()throws IOException{
    File f= new File("file.txt");          // specify the file name and path here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    System.out.println("ID  |Species    |Weight |Length |"
                       +"Num of working flippers|Time   |Date   |Location   |");
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String currentLine= sc.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = currentLine.split("#");
        System.out.println(tokens[0]+"\t"+tokens[1]+"\t\t"
                           +tokens[2]+"\t"+tokens[3]+"\t"+tokens[4]+"\t\t"+tokens[5]+"\t"
                           +tokens[6]+"\t"+tokens[7]);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

when i already add the data it shows in the text file in one line not in line by line as i already add the data before

Comment: Your array index (the number between the brackets after tokens) is out of bounds (that is, less than zero or more than the last item in the tokens array).

Comment: post the file contents in question. Your file have not a valid data according to your logic thats why exception occur.

Answer (score -3):

To avoid the ArryIndexOutOfBoundException you have to check the size of the tokens array before you expect it to have 8 elements:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
    String currentLine= sc.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = currentLine.split("#");
    if(tokens.length<8) {
        System.out.println("Invalid format in line:"+currentLine;
    } else {
        System.out.println(tokens[0]+"\t"+tokens[1]+"\t\t"+tokens[2]
          +"\t"+tokens[3]+"\t"+tokens[4]+"\t\t"+tokens[5]+"\t"
          +tokens[6]+"\t"+tokens[7]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't like this answer please tell me why so I can learn from it

Comment: I didn't down-vote it, but the question has already been asked many times before and is already answered in the duplicate question. In my opinion, it is better to close and move-on.

Comment: ok Thanks for your time @rghome